# Google Analytics - Cross Device tracking during email verification?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track a (registration) process which includes a generic email verification step. Since clicking the link in the email to the verification page can be opened in a new device - how can I encode the url to associate the differnet parts of the user session.

I need both an acurate funnel and accurate conversion attribution.

I use a utm_process parameter to diffrentiate verification from different process. Are there some parameters avaialble from Google Analytics or its visitor (__utma) or (__utmb) session cookie which can be sent with the e-mail to preserve the funnel/source/medium across devices in this use case?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, but might give you ideas:

Easy way: append the client_id (from the Google Cookie) to the confirmation url with an extra parameter. On the confirmation page check if a client id is present in the url and pass it as an argument when you create the tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'clientId': '35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b' // <- pulled from the url
});
```

More laborious way, but more in synch with the Google documentation:

Do cross device tracking via the [user_id feature](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id). Enable session unification. If somebody completed the registration create a user id and pass it to Analytics. Because of session unification it will be set for the complete session including previous pageviews (but not for previous sessions that haven't had the user id set). When the user hits the confirmation page pull the user id from your database and apply it to GA.

The downside (one of them) of the user id feature is that you need an extra view 
that will only display data from sessions that had the user id set.

Comment: Hi I already have userId implemented to supporting cross device workflows,  I'll try to code a ga plugin to read userId from the uri and put it into the tracker and let you know if it help.